# Testing Behat and Galen Framework

Tags: testing, automation, behat, galen

Is there a way to use Galen responsive testing framework together with [Behat](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/) ?

[Galen](http://galenframework.com/docs/reference-working-in-command-line/) looks like a standalone tool, and I didn't found any ready connectors for Behat.

Answer (score 0):

No there are currently no connectors for Behat.

It looks for me that Behat has it's own DSL. So it's not very easy to build a connector